# My website has terrible scrolling on mobile devices/slower computers

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I've been searching around but cannot figure out what I've done to cause such lag. I'm working on a portfolio website for someone and everything seems fine except for scrolling, which is horrible and nearly broken on an iPhone or iPad.

the website is www.willaustinactor.com - would anyone have any idea what I might be doing that is causing this issue?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What does 'horrible and nearly broken' scrolling entail?

Answer (score 2):

The semi-transparent part of the navigation, the rounded corners, the text shadows, and the custom font probably all contribute to it.

Try removing all of those things and see if it looks better, then add them back in one by one to see how much you can get away with.

If you want more detailed information, Opera (and I think the Chromium nightlies) has a CSS profiler that breaks down where the rendering time is spent.

Comment: I'd just use media queries to remove those problematic css rules for mobile devices - that way you get the best of both worlds :)

Comment: Haha, I was actually doing that as you wrote that and it had almost no effect whatsoever.

Comment: HOWEVER!

it seems the issue was having:

   overflow: auto;

In the body/html tag. Removing that fixed it (although it makes scrolling my popup div on the mobile device more difficult, but that can be remedied elsewhere.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @neo999955 you're welcome, although it looks like you figured it out yourself... I don't think you needed my help ;)

Comment: haha, ALL help helps - just pushes you in the right directions.